# Install java chaincode throws an invalid memory address error

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using 1.4.0-rc2 for docker images and java code.

When trying to install a java chaincode from the cli to a peer with the following command:

```
peer chaincode install -p github.com/hyperledger/chaincode/java/ -l java -n java_chaincode -v 0
```

Throws the following error:

```
2019-01-09 14:36:11.799 UTC [main] InitCmd -> WARN 001 CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL is no longer supported, please use the FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC environment variable
2019-01-09 14:36:11.819 UTC [main] SetOrdererEnv -> WARN 002 CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL is no longer supported, please use the FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC environment variable
2019-01-09 14:36:11.824 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2019-01-09 14:36:11.824 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0xea273b]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/container/util.WriteFolderToTarPackage.func1(0x7fffb7459543, 0x31, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1874100, 0xc0002c4a50, 0x60, 0x1691f40)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/container/util/writer.go:64 +0xcb
path/filepath.Walk(0x7fffb7459543, 0x31, 0xc0003b8c60, 0x2, 0x3)
        /opt/go/src/path/filepath/path.go:402 +0x6a
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/container/util.WriteFolderToTarPackage(0xc00011dc00, 0x7fffb7459543, 0x31, 0xc000435858, 0x3, 0x3, 0x0, 0xc00012dc80, 0xc00011dc00, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/container/util/writer.go:136 +0x241
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/container/util.WriteJavaProjectToPackage(0xc00011dc00, 0x7fffb7459543, 0x31, 0xc000435940, 0x1)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/container/util/writer.go:152 +0x158
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/platforms/java.(*Platform).GetDeploymentPayload(0x2429b40, 0x7fffb7459543, 0x32, 0x4, 0xc000167188, 0x1716e01, 0x4, 0xc0004359c0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/platforms/java/platform.go:123 +0x1e0
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/platforms.(*Registry).GetDeploymentPayload(0xc00000c540, 0x1716e08, 0x4, 0x7fffb7459543, 0x32, 0x4, 0x7fffb7459543, 0x32, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/platforms/platforms.go:103 +0x8f
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/container.GetChaincodePackageBytes(0xc00000c540, 0xc00024a5c0, 0x0, 0x16740c0, 0xc0000b2cd0, 0xc000040704, 0x4)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/container/controller.go:191 +0xc7
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode.getChaincodeDeploymentSpec(0xc00024a5c0, 0xc00024a501, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/common.go:58 +0x11c
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode.genChaincodeDeploymentSpec(0xc0000c4c80, 0x7fffb7459581, 0x1b, 0x7fffb74595a0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x8020106, 0x2)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/install.go:109 +0xac
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode.chaincodeInstall(0xc0000c4c80, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00003a4d0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/install.go:177 +0x156
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode.installCmd.func1(0xc0000c4c80, 0xc000150480, 0x0, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/install.go:44 +0x54
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc0000c4c80, 0xc000150300, 0x8, 0x8, 0xc0000c4c80, 0xc000150300)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:762 +0x473
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x2320300, 0x8, 0x0, 0x231f4c0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:852 +0x2fd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x2320300, 0xc00044ff40, 0x1)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:800 +0x2b
main.main()
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:53 +0x2f7
```

Inside that folder is a jar created following the tutorial that is [on github](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java/blob/release-1.4/TUTORIAL.md).

Edit 1:

The error above was because the path was not correct, I was using the path relative to gopath as I had to do that for the go chaincodes before, but using the full path worked for the installation.

For the instantiation:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -n chaincode -v 0 -C channel -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -l java
```

Gives the following error:

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: 1: ./build.sh: not found
"
```

This is the log for the peers:

```
2019-01-10 07:43:44.504 UTC [chaincode.platform.java] GenerateDockerBuild -> ERRO 3e9 Can't build java chaincode Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: 1: ./build.sh: not found
"
2019-01-10 07:43:44.505 UTC [chaincode.platform] func1 -> ERRO 3ea Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: 1: ./build.sh: not found
"
2019-01-10 07:43:44.505 UTC [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 3eb Error building image: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: 1:./build.sh: not found
"
2019-01-10 07:43:44.505 UTC [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 3ec Build Output:
********************

********************
2019-01-10 07:43:44.507 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 3ed [channel][6ba7c224] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (1563ms)
2019-01-10 07:43:44.507 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 3ee [channel][6ba7c224] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: 1: ./build.sh: not found
"
error starting container
error starting container
```

I will be happy to provide more info and code.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a chaincode directly from a jar is not that simple, you need to change the scripts for that or create your custom image from the jar file, I spent hours figuring out this. For,

> peer chaincode install and peer chaincode instantiate

source code is "necessary", as peer performs "docker pull" to download java specific image in order to **builds it internally** and launch the chaincode container. You can do *docker exec* to check the chaincode.jar is created inside the chaincode container.

Now coming to your *error runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference*, can you check the path if its correct, and share peer logs, i would be happy to help.

Comment: When you say the source code, you are talking about the whole gradle project or just the src folder? Thanks a lot, will add the logs.

Comment: Oh god, thanks a lot, I thought that I have to use the path relative to the gopath, as I had to do that with the go chaincodes, but it worked for me to use the whole path. So you were right, is about the path. But now when I try to instatiate gives me the following error. `Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 127 "/bin/sh: 1: ./build.sh: not found
"`

Comment: By source code I mean the gradle project without any build or jar files. here's an example https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/chaincode/chaincode_example02/java

Comment: check the peer logs by running - docker logs <peer container id>, update me on that

Comment: Thanks Harchit, I have added the log of the peer

Comment: I think it is not able to find the build.gradle file, are you using the source code? check if build.gradle and source code are present in the chain code folder

Comment: Yes, I am using the source code, I am using the fabric chaincode example gradle that is inside the repo of the [java chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java). Install does correctly but the instantiate throws the error that I have swon you.